# Draw text directly under a specified bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-recyclerview, java-canvas

```
p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(), (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
c.drawRect(background, p);
icon = getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_clear);
RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - 2 * width, (float) itemView.getTop() + width, (float) itemView.getRight() - width, (float) itemView.getBot
c.drawBitmap(icon, null, icon_dest, p); //[1]
p.setTextSize(50);
p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
c.drawText("Cancel",*/Insert x and y here*/,p);
```

So far I have that.

I'm trying to `drawText` directly under the bitmap I drawed. (`[1]`). However I'm not sure how to get the coordinates of the bitmap and adjust it so that it's centered below it.

[image]

The above image is what I'm trying to achieve. *Contents of the app has been censored.*

In conclusion, how do I get the coordinates for the text that I'm trying to get?

I'm using `onChildDraw` method of the `ItemTouchHelper` for a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paint.getTextBounds()` to get the bounds of the text that you are about to draw on the canvas. Once you get the bounds of the text, you can calculate the position to draw the text based on the icon's position.

Edit:

This aligns the text below the icon at the X position same as the icon:

```
float textX = icon_dest.left;
float textY = icon_dest.bottom + some_padding;

canvas.drawText("Cancel", textX, textY, textPaint);
```

This aligns the center of the icon and the center of the text in a same vertical line:

```
Rect textBounds = new Rect();
textPaint.getTextBounds("Cancel", 0, length, textBounds);

float iconCenterX = icon_dest.left + (icon_dest.width() / 2);
float textHalfWidth = (textBounds.right - textBounds.left) / 2;

float textX = iconCenterX - textHalfWidth;
float textY = icon_dest.bottom + somePadding

canvas.drawText("Cancel", textX, textY, textPaint);
```

Comment: Further explanation and an example would be nice

Comment: To be specific, "Calculate the position", and how would you do that?

Comment: Also, I'm using `RectF`, not `Rect`, so I can't use `getTextBounds()` as there's no parameter for a `RectF` instead of a `Rect`

Comment: Thanks, but `RectF` doesn't seem to have a `getLeft()` or `getBottom()`;

Comment: You have the icon's bounds in icon_dest. Using that add the necessary padding to position the text.

Comment: Ok. I wrote it in kotlin. and hand converted to Java. Looks like left, bottom are public fields. you can access directly. I wil edit it.

Comment: If you want the text bounds, use getTextBounds(). For that you have to give a new empty Rect(), not the same RectF(). If the above code works, you dont need the text bounds at all.

Comment: I have added another example which aligns the center of icon and text.